# Angular : ng serve works but ng serve --open does not

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, npm, cmd

I have recently started with Angular and I am new to it. I have installed nodejs and typescript as well.
When i go to my project directory using the command prompt, the ng serve commands works and compiles the project and i need to open the browser manually. However, when i try it with the --open parameter, i am getting an error in the events.js file as:

throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event

ERROR: spawn cmd ENOENT

My versions are :

Angular CLI: 10.0.4
Node: 12.18.3
npm: 6.14.6
OS: win32 x64
tsc: 3.9.7

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be some library inconsistency. Try:

1. delete **node_modules** and **package-lock.json**
2. run npm update
3. run npm install